# dbus-daemon is crashing

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, systemd, dbus

After Lubuntu 18.04 installation, the system didn't boot, so I started root shell in recovery mode. I've observed that all systemd commands (e.g. `systemctl list-sockets`) are very slow or time out. My attempts to debug this:

- Looking at the output of `strace -p 1` I've observed that systemd PID 1 is waiting in a *ppoll(2)* system call to receive data on the dbus socket, but that data never arrives.
- Output of `ps ax | grep dbus` contains `919 ? Zs 0:0 [dbus-daemon]  <defunct>`, and the PID changes every few minutes.
- `systemctl list-jobs` is very slow (or times out), it displays `1950 dbus.service start waiting`.
- `journalctl -u dbus.service -b -f` dispays a few instances of `Started D-Bus System Message Bus`; 90 seconds later: `dbus.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`. It doesn't show any other messages (e.g. the error message by `dbus-daemon`).

I suspect that the root cause of `systemctl ...` timeouts is that `dbus.service` crashes shortly after it starts. How do I debug this further? Where can I see the logs (+ stdout + stderr) of `dbus.service`?

I'm new to systemd and dbus. I have some Linux debugging skills from the pre-systemd times.

Comment: You can use ```journalctl -xe``` to see the systemd logs. But also you can manually start the dbus service to see what happens. The exact command-line arguments are in the ```ExecStart``` option of the ```/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service``` file which is the actual service. For example mine is : ```/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only```

Comment: It doesn't start with this command, because it's expecting a socket from systemd, which the interactive Bash doesn't have.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to debug this by removing `--syslog-only` from `/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service`, and then `journalctl -u dbus -b -f` displayed a relevant error message: `Failed to start message bus: Error getting AppArmor context of bus: Permission denied`. I solved it by disabling AppArmor for dbus.

After this, X11 (lightdm) goes into an infinite crash loop, and in `text` boot mode I'm logged out (without an error message) in 1 second after a correct password input at console login.

I suspect the Lubuntu 18.04 installer is not compatible with online package updates from Ubuntu 18.04. Since then I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 (instead of Lubuntu) to this computer, and that one works out of the box. I was also able to install and use the Lubuntu and MATE desktop environments under Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What has caused the AppArmor to prevent dbus from running ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi: All I know is in my answer. I suspect the Lubuntu 18.04 installer is not compatible with online package updates from Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: No issues have yet been discovered in QA-testing of Lubuntu 18.04.5 (*which was delayed a week just today*), nor any with 18.04.4 ISOs (testing was completed prior to release, so won't have been with any packages you installed, but new packages are examined via CI looking for issues).  If you believe it's a bug, please file it (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and we'll examine issue.

Comment: Bug reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1883865

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to report this bug and helping to make Ubuntu better  (please run apport-collect as requested, and thanks for posting the link; I'd missed it)